# Change parentheses to square-brackets when using CForm

Tags: export, output-formatting, string-manipulation

I'm not experienced with *Mathematica*, but am learning to appreciate its awesome power for manipulations.

I get the an expression like this when using `CForm` (I cut it short to simplify):

```
T(0, 0) + ht*((-((T(-1, 0) + T(0, 0))*u(-0.5, 0))
```

In *Mathematica*, `T, u` are functions. But they should be arrays in my C code. Can I tell *Mathematica* that when it is exporting `T, u` to C, it should treat them as arrays and use `[]`?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
I haven't written any C in a long while, so I forgot its syntax for multidimensional arrays, i.e. `array[first][second]`! Here is the amended code:

```
ToString[CForm[t[12, 156] + ht u[5, 3]]]

StringReplace[%, {
  "t(" ~~ Shortest[a__] ~~ "," ~~ Shortest[b__] ~~ ")" -> "t[" ~~ a ~~ "][" ~~ b ~~ "]", 
  "u(" ~~ Shortest[a__] ~~ "," ~~ Shortest[b__] ~~ ")" -> "u[" ~~ a ~~ "][" ~~ b ~~ "]"
  }]

(* Out: "t[12][156] + ht*u[5][3]" *)
```

**Original answer:**
If it is acceptable to you to deal with strings for your C code, you could convert to a string, then apply a string pattern:

```
ToString[CForm[t[12, 156] + ht u[5, 3]]]

StringReplace[%,
 {
  "t(" ~~ Shortest[a__] ~~ "," ~~ Shortest[b__] ~~ ")" -> "t[" ~~ a ~~ "," ~~ b ~~ "]",
  "u(" ~~ Shortest[a__] ~~ "," ~~ Shortest[b__] ~~ ")" -> "u[" ~~ a ~~ "," ~~ b ~~ "]"
  }
]

(* Out: "t[12,156] + ht*u[5,3]" *)
```

The `Shortest[a__]` forms are there to handle cases in which the arguments to the functions are longer than one character.

Comment: thanks for the input. However, this seems to not work more generally: If I throw in a few exta parentheses inside what I want to become square-brackets, Mathematica gets the pattern wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica's [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm) will convert [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) expressions to arrays, so you can achieve what you want by changing your functions to [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) expressions:

```
ReplaceAll[
    HoldForm[T[0,0]+ht (-(T[-1,0]+T[0,0]) u[-.5,0])],
    {T[a_,b_]:>T[[a,b]], u[a_,b_]:>u[[a,b]]}
] //CForm
```

> T[0][0] + ht*(-(T[-1][0] + T[0][0])*u[-0.5][0])

Another possibility is to teach [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm) about your functions:

```
Format[T[a_, b_], CForm] := HoldForm[T[[a, b]]]
Format[u[a_, b_], CForm] := HoldForm[u[[a, b]]]
```

Your example:

```
T[0,0]+ht (-(T[-1,0]+T[0,0]) u[-.5,0]) //CForm
```

> T[0][0] + ht*(-T[-1][0] - T[0][0])*u[-0.5][0]